# Como fazer os dados aparecerem nos campos em AngularJS

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Estou entrando com um cep e uma busca é feita e me traz os outros dados...
Porém, quero que os dados sejam exibidos, cada um no seu respectivo campo, pois serão inseridos no banco de dados.
Como proceder?

html:

```
<body ng-controller="appController">
<div align="center">
<form>
<table width="100">
    <label>CEP </label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cep" ng-blur="pegaCep()"><br>
    <label>Estado </label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.uf"><br>
    <label>Cidade </label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cidade" size="30"><br>
    <label>Bairro </label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.bairro" size="30"><br>
    <label>Rua </label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.logradouro" size="30"><br>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http){
$scope.endereco = {}
$scope.pegaCep = function () {
    $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (endereco){
        console.log(endereco);
        $scope.endereco = endereco;
    });
 }

});
```

php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$cep = $_GET['cep'];
//print_r($cep);

include('correios.class.php');
if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
$correios = Correios::cep($_GET['cep']);
$correios = json_encode($correios[0]);
    die($correios);
}elseif(isset($_GET['codigo_rastreio'])){
    die(json_encode(Correios::rastreio($_GET['codigo_rastreio'])));
}else{
    die('informe parametro GET cep ou codigo_rastreio');
}
?>
```

[image: Retorno]

Comment: Pode incluir um exemplo do conteúdo retornado pela URL `php/pegaCep.php` ?

Comment: [{"cliente":"","logradouro":"Beco A (Estr Cristiano Kraemer)","bairro":"Vila Nova","cep":"91750073","cidade":"Porto Alegre","uf":"RS"}]

Answer (score 5):

Você está utilizando o serviço `$http`. O objeto retornado inclui vários parâmetros. Faça as seguintes mudanças no seu código:

```
$scope.endereco = {};

$scope.pegaCep = function () {
    $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (retorno){
        console.log(retorno);
        $scope.endereco = retorno.data;
    });
 }
```

Perceba que a propriedade `data` contém o valor retornado.

Propriedades do objeto retornado pelo serviço $http:

- **data** – `{string|Object}` – o conteúdo da resposta, devidamente transformada.
- **status** – `{number}` – Código HTTP retornado.
- **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – função para retorno de cabeçalhos.
- **config** – `{Object}` – O objeto de configuração da requisição original.
- **statusText** – `{string}` – O status HTTP em formato de texto.

Referência: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Mesmo com essa mudança no código, os dados não aparecem.

Comment: @GustavoSevero No log do browser - pode confirmar se o endpoint está retornando algum conteúdo *quando chamado pela função, e não diretamente*?

Comment: @lbotinelly não seria o caso de usar um `$apply();`? Ou de atribuir diretamente o valor ao campo? ex.: `$scope.endereco.logradouro = retorno.data.logradouro`. Lembro que já passei por isso e só assim resolveu

Comment: Sim, está retornando, eu já postei o retorno dos dados:

 
[{"cliente":"","logradouro":"Beco A (Estr Cristiano Kraemer)","bairro":"Vila Nova","cep":"91750073","cidade":"Porto Alegre","uf":"RS"}]

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, aparece uma mensagem no console dizendo que logradouro não é reconhecido

Comment: @CelsomTrindade $apply() deve ser utilizado apenas em situações especiais, onde o modelo não recebe a propagação de eventos do $digest. O caso atual me parece bem simples, e não haveria necessidade.

Comment: @GustavoSevero se você está recebendo esta mensagem o objeto não está corretamente formado. Seu erro é outro - o valor enviado como parâmetro para o endpoint, ou a interpretação, por parte do serviço, do parâmetro enviado.

Comment: Vou postar o endpoit para vocês verem. Vejam no post

Comment: @GustavoSevero outra coisa - inicialize o objeto `$scope.endereco` antes de utilizá-lo na view, guarantindo assim que o modelo $scope.endereco.cep exista. Eu atualizei minha resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Veja se é isso que vc sugeriu... Coloquei no post.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Sim, exatamente. Está obtendo o mesmo erro?

Comment: Nada, não aparecem os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Como alternativa à resposta do amigo @lbotinelly, quando passei por uma situação semelhante, o que resolveu o meu problema foi aplicar diretamente o valor para cada campo, deste modo:

```
$scope.pegaCep = function () {
    $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (retorno){
        $scope.endereco.cep = retorno.data.cep;
        $scope.endereco.logradouro = retorno.data.logradouro;
        //etc..
    });
};
```

Ou o uso do `$apply()` (em último caso).

Caso ainda assim não resolva o seu problema, verifique se o console realmente exibe os dados como você os espera.

```
$scope.pegaCep = function () {
    $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (retorno){
        console.log(retorno.data);
    });
}
```

Pois o problema pode não estar no AngularJS.

#### Obs.:

Utilize a minha resposta em último caso, a dele está do modo correto.

Comment: Aparece no console "Cannot read property 'cep' of undefined""

Comment: O que o console disso aqui: `console.log(retorno.data)` mostra?

Comment: Isso:

0: Object
bairro: "Vila Nova"
cep: "91750073"
cidade: "Porto Alegre"
cliente: ""
logradouro: "Beco A (Estr Cristiano Kraemer)"
uf: "RS"

Comment: Consegue print? Acho que sua array que não está sendo gerada corretamente

Comment: Segue o print no post

Comment: estranho.... tente a minha resposta, mas ao invés de `$scope.endereco.cep = retorno.data.cep;` faça como o Nicholas propos: `$scope.endereco.cep = retorno.data[0].cep;` veja se funciona.

Comment: Consegui, tive que fazer ajustes no endpoint, no php, vejam no post

Comment: Beleza! Mas evite de colocar a resolução do problema na pergunta. Coloque como resposta, pois se mais alguém tiver o mesmo problema, saberá como resolver.

Answer (score 0):

[{"cliente":"","logradouro":"Beco A (Estr Cristiano Kraemer)","bairro":"Vila Nova","cep":"91750073","cidade":"Porto Alegre","uf":"RS"}]

Já que o retorno do php é esse acima, você precisa fazer o seguinte:

```
app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http){
$scope.endereco = {}
$scope.pegaCep = function () {
    $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (endereco){

        $scope.endereco = endereco.data[0];
    });
 }

});
```

agora vai funcionar

Comment: Aparece no console "ReferenceError: endereco is not defined"

Comment: Eu estou me baseando no código que voce mandou na pergunta, é o mesmo que está atualmente?

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha feito uma alteração... Sim, está igual
Agora a resposta no console é "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"